# Execute my PowerShell script does not work via my C# application

Tags: c#, powershell, ffmpeg, camera

I'm currently working on IP cameras for my job, but I'm just starting out because I've never done anything like this before.
The aim is very simple, to start recording a specific camera via a user action, and to stop the same camera via another user action.
To achieve this, I looked for several solutions and finally decided to use FFMPEG and two Powershell scripts.

The first starts recording using FFMPEG and stores the process PID in a .txt file.

**StartRec.ps1**

```
#Paramètres de la caméra IP
$cameraIP = $args[0]
$port = $args[1]
$username = $args[2]
$password = $args[3]

$ipfile = ${cameraIP} -replace "\.", ""
$namefile = "video_"+$ipfile+"_"+(Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".mp4"
$namepidfile = "PID_"+$ipfile+".txt"

# URL du flux vidéo de la caméra (exemple générique, adaptez-le à votre caméra)
$videoStreamUrl = "rtsp://${username}:${password}@${cameraIP}:${port}/videoMain"

# Répertoire de sortie pour la vidéo enregistrée
$outputDirectory = "C:\OutputDirectory"

# Chemin complet du fichier de sortie (nom de fichier avec horodatage actuel)
$outputFile = Join-Path $outputDirectory (${namefile})

# Commande FFmpeg pour enregistrer le flux vidéo en arrière-plan
$ffmpegCommand = "ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i `"$videoStreamUrl`" -c:v copy `"$outputFile`"" 

# Démarrer FFmpeg en arrière-plan
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c $ffmpegCommand" -PassThru

$cheminFichier = Join-Path $outputDirectory $namepidfile

if (-not (Test-Path $cheminFichier)) {
    # Le fichier n'existe pas, créer le fichier
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $cheminFichier -Force
    Write-Host "Fichier créé : $cheminFichier"
} else {
    Write-Host "Le fichier existe déjà : $cheminFichier"
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$processId = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='ffmpeg.exe'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId

# Enregistrez le PID dans un fichier
$process.Id | Out-File $cheminFichier

Write-Host "Enregistrement démarré. PID du processus : $($processId)"
```

The second reads the contents of this .txt file, stores it in a variable as a PID and stops the process via its Id, then closes the command window associated with this process (which tells the camera that the recording is finished).

**StoptRec.ps1**

```
$cameraIP = $args[0]
$ipfile = ${cameraIP} -replace "\.", ""
$namepidfile = "PID_"+$ipfile+".txt"
$outputDirectory = "C:\OutputDirectory"
$cheminFichier = Join-Path $outputDirectory $namepidfile

$pidcontent = Get-Content $cheminFichier -Raw 
if (-not $pidContent) {
    Write-Host "Erreur : Le fichier PID est vide. Assurez-vous que l'enregistrement est démarré."
    exit
}

$processId  = $pidContent.Trim() -as [int]

if (-not $processId) {
    Write-Host "Erreur : Impossible de convertir le contenu du fichier PID en entier."
    exit
}

Get-Process -Id $processId

Stop-Process -Id $processId -PassThru | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }

Write-Host "Enregistrement arrêté pour le processus PID $processId"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
```

The problem is that they work, except in one case that I'll explain:
First, I tried to run them via PowerShell, the recording starts up and the script works as expected, as does the shutdown. My final file is usable.
I then performed C# actions in my Controller, which calls and executes these scripts:

**The action that calls StartRec.ps1**

```
        public void startRecordingCam1(string ipAddress)
        {
            string ps1File = @"C:\OutputDirectory\StartRec.ps1";
            string cameraIP = "Camera IP Adress";
            string port = "88";
            string username = "Username";
            string password = "Password";

            Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"{ps1File}\" \"{cameraIP}\" \"{port}\" \"{username}\" \"{password}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true
                //CreateNoWindow = true
            });
        }
```

**The action that calls StopRec.ps1**

```
       public void stopRecording(string ipAddress)
        {
            string ps1File = @"C:\Projet Valentin\CameraTest\StopRec_Csharp.ps1";
            string cameraIP = "10.0.1.10";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{ps1File}\" \"{cameraIP}\" ",
                UseShellExecute = true
            };
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
```

When I run the two scripts via these actions, StartRec.ps1 works well, but StopRec.ps1 doesn't work completely: the process is stopped, but the command window isn't closed, so camera recording continues (despite the end of the process).
As both scripts worked perfectly when launched with Powershell, but not with the C# application, I tried several combinations of "Start-Stop" with "PowerShell/C#".

If I run StartRec.PS1 with the C# application and StopRec.PS1 with PowerShell, it works.
If I run StartRec.PS1 with PowerShell and StopRec.PS1 with the C# application, it works.
If I run StartRec.PS1 with PowerShell and StopRec.PS1 with PowerShell, it works.
The only case that doesn't work is when I run both via the C# application

One thing I can add that I discovered while debugging is that this :
`Stop-Process -Id $processId -PassThru | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }`

Returns false in the only case where it doesn't work, and true in all other cases

That's all the details I can give you, thanks for your help!

Comment: It sound like you do not have permission to stop the process or the process is already terminated (maybe due to an exception).  Why do you need to close the window?  Window may close by itself when the process ends.